# How do I factory reset a ESP8266MOD

Tags: esp8266, reset

I have a ESP8266MOD, that I tried to flash over the air with mdash from mongoose os. I had originally done the following steps from this turotial https://mongoose-os.com/docs/mongoose-os/quickstart/setup.md steps 1-9 seemed to work fine, but when I tried step to update the firmware over the air, it seemed to upload but I never got the console in mongoose to display anything like the guide says. I unplugged my device, and plugged back in and no longer could connect to wifi, I tried reconfiguring wifi but it did not work. I want to factory reset, but I posted in mongoose os forums and they said I need to setup a button to pin GPIO0. I have attempted to do so seen in this picture. I am stuck at this point for the button does nothing noticable.

[image]

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: Hi! (mostly, for future readers) By the way, yes, the 8266 should have a bootloader in ROM, but it's by no means so that you can factory-reset just any microcontroller / SoC.

Comment: good point @MarcusMuller, factory reset is usually considered a system/product-level concern

Answer (score 1):

GPIO0 on the ESP8266 is used to invoke the bootloader at startup.

Have a look here: https://github.com/espressif/esptool/wiki/ESP8266-Boot-Mode-Selection

GPIO0 = LOW means serial bootloader mode is active. That is to say, if GPIO0 reads low at power on / reset, it runs the serial bootloader out of ROM.